# How to update text box id dyamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have taken this code from [here](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery?).

If I want to delete a text box, how can I update the rest of text box `id`s? For example, if I delete the text box at the third line, then my text box at the 4th line should now have an `id` of *3*, instead of *4*.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10; /
        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); 
        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button");     
        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ 
                x++; 
                $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
        <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id =" + x + "></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why do you need the ids?

Comment: And why do they have to be sequential? All that matters is that they're unique.

Comment: You should not update ids of textboxes, instead of that you should update ids in your js which will be doing some manipulations based upon it.

Comment: instead of relying on `x` for how many, check the number of inputs.

Comment: if i delete any textbox in between all id's must be updated for say if i delete textbox at 2nd row the with id 2 then 3rd textbox should automatically get id 3 not 2 after removal

Comment: `$("element").attr("id", newId);`

Comment: If it really matters to you, I would just loop through each textbox and replace all IDs when one gets deleted, then you don't have to bother checking which one has been deleted

Answer (score 0):

its easy, give all your `textboxes` a `class`, name can be anything,
after that get all you textboxes with jquery's class selector like this

```
$(".your-class-name")
```

this return an array of `textboxes`.
then you iterate over that array like this,

```
$(".your-class-name").forEach(function(textbox,i) {
   $(textbox).attr('id', i+1); // i is the index, starts with 0
});
```

this will iterate every all you textboxes

Comment: Did you give classes to you text boxes ?

Comment: Post your code here, so I can see what's not working